# Unity SteamVR - force detach from hand

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I have `interactable/throwable` VR objects in my game. The thing is that when I hold this object in hand and move him in area of other object trigger I want to force detach this object from hand.

```
    public void DetachFromHand() //Added method in Interactable.cs
    {
        OnDetachedFromHand(attachedToHand);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
       other.gameObject.GetComponent<Valve.VR.InteractionSystem.Interactable>().DetachFromHand();
    }
```

`GetComponent<Valve.VR.InteractionSystem.Interactable>()` returns null even though object I hold has `Interactable` script added.
What's more I think this isn't the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try detaching the object by using `hand.DetachObject(gameObject);`